# /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by...)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, libstdc++

Trying to test my program but these errors come up:

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ws)
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ws)
```

Here's what I'm using to compile it (as requested by my college):

```
/usr/local/gcc/9.1.0/bin/g++ -Wall -std=c++17 -g -o ws w2_p2.cpp
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: An attempt is made to run an executable on a system that has the wrong version of the C++ library, that's what the error means. Unfortunately, nobody will be able to tell you how to "fix these errors", this requires specialized knowledge, and investigation into what libraries the C++ code was linked it, when it was compiled, and what libraries are on the system that's attempting to run this executable.

Comment: your compiler being installed in /usr/local, you'll probably find the corresponding libstdc++.so in /usr/local/gcc/9.1.0/lib64. Either prepend the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to this location or set your rpath in gcc's options with something like -Wl,-rpath,'/usr/local/gcc/9.1.0/lib64